# Calculating location of a complex pole of a Scattering Matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation, dirac-delta-distributions, s-matrix-theory

I am asked to calculate a pole in the lower complex momentum plane of an element from the Scattering Matrix for the potential  $ V(x) = V_{0}(δ(x-1)+δ(x+1)$ . The potential parity even so it easier to use the parity preserving wave function for the scattering states and calculate the $S_{++}$ element of the matrix, which turns out to be

$$
S_{++} =-e^{-2ik} \frac{2ke^{-ik}-iU_{0}(e^{ik}+e^{-ik})}{-2ke^{-ik}-iU_{0}(e^{ik}+e^{-ik})}  .\tag{1}
$$

It is straightforward to show that the poles of this element are given by the equation

$$
e^{2ik} = -(1-\frac{2ik}{U_{0}})(2)
$$
I am given the final result for the momentum in the $V_{0} >>1$ realm which is approximately given by $ k = π/2 +a-iγ$ with $$ a=-\frac{π}{2U_{0}}+\frac{π}{2U_{0}^2},\qquad γ =\frac{π^2}{4U_{0}^2}. $$

I tried finding the taylor expansion for $(2)$ and equating the imaginary parts and the real parts after inserting the ansatz i have for $k$ but the results look nothing like the ones I need to find. After some research, I found a tip which said to expand in orders of $\frac{k}{U_{0}}$ which is $<<1$ and ignore terms of 3rd power but I have no idea how to do that. I am looking for any hints for my calculation, thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "calculate a pole"? You mean find it's location in the complex plane?

Comment: Yes, please excuse my English.

Comment: Is $U_0$ the same as $V_0$?

Comment: They are proportional to each other, $U_{0} = \frac{2mV_{0}}{hbar^{2}}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is straightforward to show that the poles of this element are given by the equation
> $$
> e^{2ik} = -(1-\frac{2ik}{U_{0}})(2)
> $$

Take the log of both sides:
$$
2ik = i\pi + \ln\left({1-\frac{2ik}{U_0}}\right)\;.
$$

Next use the well-known expansion of $\ln(1-x)$ for small $x$:
$$
\ln(1-x) = -x - \frac{x^2}{2} -\ldots\;,
$$
to obtain an algebraic equation that you can solve for $k$ at first or second order (e.g., a linear equation at first order, a quadradic equation at second order).

---

For example, at linear order, we find that the transcendental equation reduces to a linear equation:
$$
2ik = i\pi -\frac{2ik}{U_0}\;,
$$
which can be solved for k to find:
$$
k = \frac{\pi}{2} - \frac{\pi}{2U_0} + \ldots
$$

---

Alternatively, instead of taking the log and then expanding, one can just expand the exponential. It could be helpful to first write:
$$
k = \pi/2 + \delta\;,
$$
where $\delta$ turns out to be real at first order and corresponds to your $a$.

Then expanding the exponential to linear order, you can see that:
$$
2i\delta = \frac{-i\pi}{U_0}\frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{U_0}}\;,
$$
then expanding the last factor shows that $\delta$ equals your same expression for $a$ in terms of $U_0$, up to order $1/U_0^2$.

Next, it might be helpful to return to the full equation and write:
$$
\delta = \frac{-\pi}{2U_0}(1-\frac{1}{U_0}) + i\epsilon\;,
$$
where it will turn out that $\epsilon$ is real at lowest order and corresponds to your $-\gamma$.

Expanding the exponential to second order results in some cancelations due to our definitions and an equation for $\epsilon$ like:
$$
4\epsilon = -\frac{\pi^2}{U_0^2}(1-\frac{1}{U_0})^2 + O(\epsilon^2) + O(\epsilon/U_0)\;,
$$
but since we see that $\epsilon$ is of order $1/U_0^2$ we can just write:
$$
\epsilon = -\frac{\pi^2}{4U_0^2} + O(1/U_0^3)\;,
$$
which agrees with your expected expression for $-\gamma$, up to order $1/U_0^2$.

Comment: Thank you very much! My final equation for $ε$ had one more term $2iεδ$ that also vanishes for the same approximation reasons.

Comment: You are welcome.